# spring project with multiple issues when executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

My spring project, wich configuration is based in java code, it's returning a 404 error when I try run it through eclipse. Below I list my configuration classes. Anyone can point me what's wrong with them? I figure out nothing, despite working on it a while. In eclipse console, no error or exceptions are displayed.

A secondary problem with the application, it's related to hibernate. I create a database with the pgadmin3 (from postgresql), and when I run the application, it should create the tables on the database based on my entities, but this it's not happening (no error is displayed related to this, too).

**WebAppInitializer.java**

```
@Order(value=1)
public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) {
      // Create the 'root' Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(WebAppConfig.class);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      //container.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));

      // Create the dispatcher servlet's Spring application context
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      dispatcherContext.register(DispatcherConfig.class);

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");
    }

}
```

**WebAppConfig.java**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(value="org.webapp")
@Configuration
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/fonts/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/image/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

}
```

**DispatcherConfig.java**

```
@Controller
@Import(WebAppConfig.class)
public class DispatcherConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

**persistense.properties**

```
jdbc.driverClassname=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/webapp1?charSet=LATIN1
jdbc.user=klebermo
jdbc.pass=123
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

**HibernateConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence.properties" })
@ComponentScan({ "org.webapp.persistence" })
public class HibernateConfig {

   @Autowired
   private Environment env;

   @Bean
   public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
      LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
      sessionFactory.setDataSource(restDataSource());
      sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "org.webapp.persistence.model" });
      sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

      return sessionFactory;
   }

   @Bean
   public DataSource restDataSource() {
      BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
      dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassname"));
      dataSource.setUrl(env.getProperty("jdbc.url"));
      dataSource.setUsername(env.getProperty("jdbc.user"));
      dataSource.setPassword(env.getProperty("jdbc.pass"));

      return dataSource;
   }

   @Bean
   @Autowired
   public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
      HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
      txManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

      return txManager;
   }

   @Bean
   public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
      return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
   }

   Properties hibernateProperties() {
      return new Properties() {
         /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        {
            setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
            setProperty("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
            setProperty("hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers", "true");
         }
      };
   }
```

Full code of the project -> https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1

Comment: What URL are you trying to send your request to?

Comment: localhost:8080/webapp2/ I am running the application in my own development machine.

Comment: And do you have any handler for the path `/`? Any controllers?

Comment: yes, i have the spring security configured, which redirect to the login page. SecurityConfig->https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1/blob/master/src/org/webapp/security/SecurityConfig.java

Comment: my controller (one of them): https://github.com/klebermo/webapp1/blob/master/src/org/webapp/controller/AcessoController.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One mistake is definitely that you have annotated `DispatcherConfig` with `@Controller` instead of `@Configuration`

The second problem you mention is probably due to the fact that you have set
`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update` instead of `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

Comment: Ok, the part of DispathcerConfig, silly mistake mine, fixed asap. About the hbm2ddl.auto, I always used update, and the tables were created without problems, but now, nothing happens. By the way, the application still aren't running, despite all corrections I made.

Comment: I always used create-drop the first time and update after. Could you post the output that is displayed when the application starts-up?

Comment: Ok, actually there is one error displayed in the console (but is displayed in the start of the messages, when normally it's the last thing displayed - because that I don't see them until now). In the case, seems I have one problem with the injection of the Dao class UsuarioHome. The complete content of the message is: http://www.klebermota.eti.br/wp-content/erro.txt

Comment: never mind, I solve the problem with the solution presented in this other topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23072015/error-in-dao-class-when-using-generics

Comment: @KleberMota Glad you fixed it!